# photoshop cs6 grouping layers still allow inside layers to be selected

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do i prevent this..

Whenever i group layers and try to move them around only the layer my mouse is clicking moves.
What's the point of grouping then? I know it worked in cs5.

Is my photoshop bugged?

Comment: Do you have the group layer selected? Only if you link layers you can select a single one of them and when you move them they all move. Selecting an individual layer inside a group will not do the same.

Comment: no even when i am on background layer and just try to click & drag one layer that is part of group only that one moves. Even though i didn't specifically went to layer panel and selected inside layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: next to the "Auto-Select" check box, a drop down menu specifies what gets selected. It selects the whole group if it says "Group" (and not just one layer inside the group).

Answer (score 0):

With the **Move tool** active, uncheck **Auto-Select Layer** in the control bar.

Comment: i want to be able to select layers that not grouped individually just by clicking but not the ones that are grouped.